# How can I detect multiple touches in Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

*Hello everyone,*

I am quite new to Flutter and wanted to build an application that **detects multiple touches** and **if that touch lasts longer sets a circle** there for example.

Similar to this there is the app **"Chwazi Finger Chooser"** in the PlayStore. This is how the whole thing should look like in the end.

Can you help me and tell me which components I need? **Or if possible suggest some code?**

I have not found an answer through my research so far and am hoping for you now!

**Please help me :)**

Answer (score 1):

GestureDetector doesnt detect multi-touch, except predefined gestures like scaling etc

For multi-touch i use something like:

```
RawGestureDetector(
      gestures: {
        MultiTapGestureRecognizer: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<MultiTapGestureRecognizer>(
          () => MultiTapGestureRecognizer(),
          (MultiTapGestureRecognizer instance) {
            instance.onTapDown =(pointer, details) {
              log( 'X=${details.localPosition.dx}  Y=${details.localPosition.dy}' )
            };
          },  
        ),
      },
      child:
        ...some content widget here,
    )
)
```

To detect the end of each touch, use onTapUp()

Answer (score 0):

check the `GestureDetector` widget
and those available events https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/gestures

however Using `OnGestureListener` to detect multitouch gestures does not seem to be implemented by default.

The first thing you may have tried is reading `event.pointerCount` to get the count of fingers on the screen. However, this will be equal to 1. This is because you will (quite likely) never be able touch the screen with both fingers in exactly the same millisecond.

**Fixing it**

You have to buffer pointerCount (the amount of fingers on screen). First add those variables somewhere in the context that you intend to track gestures in:

```
// track how many fingers are used

var bufferedPointerCount = 1
var bufferTolerance = 500 // in ms
var pointerBufferTimer = Timer()
```

Then, in the onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent) function, you add this:

```
    // Buffer / Debounce the pointer count
if (event.pointerCount > bufferedPointerCount) {
  bufferedPointerCount = event.pointerCount
  pointerBufferTimer = fixedRateTimer("pointerBufferTimer", true, bufferTolerance, 1000) {
    bufferedPointerCount = 1
    this.cancel() // a non-recurring timer
  }
```

}

Essentially this tracks the maximum amount of fingers on the display and keeps it valid for bufferTolerance milliseconds (here: 500).

Comment: Thanks, very much. But how does for example a circle appears at the Location where the touch is?

Comment: check CustomPainter widget , I think it will help and check this https://github.com/nateshmbhat/touchablehttps://github.com/nateshmbhat/touchable



and if you found the previous answer about detecting multitoutch pls upvote and mark it as answered

Comment: I will try it when i have time. If i need help i will ask for it and hopefully somebody (or you) can help me :D i really want an app like chwazi finger chooser, thats my goal